# Date + days calculator

Tags: java, date, calculator

I want to create a JAVA-program that show me some dates.

A box where I insert a date.     ex. 26/10/2013
Another box where I insert a number of days that I want to add to the date in the first box.
And an answerbox that show the resultdate.

**Ex1**.      26/10/2013 + 148 days =  a date
**Ex2**.      24/12/1980 + 9245 days = a date

**Box1**:     26/10/2013 + **Box2**:     148  =  **Answer**:   23/03/2014

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.OCTOBER, 26);
gcal.add(Calendar.DATE, 148);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String answer = sdf.format(gcal.getTime());
```

// output in default time zone (my zone: 23/03/2014)

Comment: In a totally newbie in JAVA.
I have programmed a little bit in Visual Basic many years ago.
In VB I would make something like this:

Answer.text = Date1.text + Days.text

or something like that.

Comment: @user3434864 Okay, shown code is your calculator. About "box", maybe you can use Swing as UI (JTextField?) or a website with a input control (HTML). There are so many different UI strategies. How about first looking in a Java introduction book?

Comment: I have seen tutorials videos in youtube, but I can`t find a tutorials that show me about my idea ?

Here is what I have coded:
import java.util.Scanner;

class datefinder{
 public static void main(Sting args[]){
  Scanner finder = new Scanner(System.in)
  double date1, days, answer;
  System.out.println("Enter the startdate");
  date1 = finder.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter days to add");
  days = finder.nextDouble();
  answer =date1 + days;
  System.out.println(answer);
 }
}

Comment: @user3434864 I recommend to put such code fragments in your question, in comment it is hard to read. And by the way, a double is not a good type for a date input, why not using String in your format dd/MM/yyyy and then parsing it using SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: `import java.util.Scanner
class datefinder{ public static void main(Sting args[]){
Scanner finder = new Scanner(System.in)
double date1, days, answer;
System.out.println("Enter the startdate");
date1 = finder.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter days to add");
days = finder.nextDouble();
answer =date1 + days;
System.out.println(answer);
}
}`